# Can we correct the OverflowAI blog post's GenAI announcement?

Tags: support, blog

> A GenAI Stack Exchange will serve as a place for a community that is centered around knowledge sharing: posting questions and answers about things like prompt engineering, model training, and the broader field of machine learning.
> <sub>[Announcing OverflowAI](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/27/announcing-overflowai/)</sub>

Oops!  This is not correct (machine learning is hard off-topic; model training is [or will be in the near future] likely almost entirely off topic); it may worsen our problems with scope.

**Question**: Can we correct the OverflowAI blog post's GenAI announcement?

I suggest changing it to

> ...about things like getting the most out of using genAI.

or

> ...about things like using the rapidly evolving plethora of genAI tools.

---

As a side note, [Prashanth Chandrasekar's talk](https://www.youtube.com/live/g5F5t205pYA?feature=share&t=2074) briefly announces *GenAI Stack Exchange*, and says:

> ...this past week we've launched two things one is generative AI stack exchange which is an area specifically that you can go to today you can go join it and it's all about prompt engineering prompt design you know this is obviously going to be fundamental as we think about software development in the future so we wanted to create a space where you can learn about that subject so that's already active and you can join it...

This is perfectly fine.

---

The [labs page](https://stackoverflow.co/labs/) has this:

> We’ve launched the GenAI Stack Exchange site: a site for Q&A on writing or engineering effective prompts while utilizing different generative AI tools.

This is also fine.

Comment: Thanks for flagging. I will chase this down.

Comment: @SpencerG I think the correction should be to clarify that the community is discussing the site attributes. A few days ago, I asked a question about using conversational APIs (it looks that they might be a better option than GPT APIs for some use cases), but I haven't time yet to "escalate" the discussion about its topicality. However, it would be nice to have a statement about the site *invariables* (already decided site attributes restrictions / parameters that will not be changed during a specific time frame).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cool, it's fixed now:

> GenAI Stack Exchange will serve as a place for a community that is centered around knowledge sharing: posting questions and answers about things like prompt engineering, getting the most out of AI, and staying on top the rapidly evolving ecosystem of GenAi Tools.
> <sub>[Announcing OverflowAI](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/27/announcing-overflowai/)</sub>